# MongoDB : query collection based on Date

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB in  this format

```
db.logins.find().pretty()
{
        "cust_id" : "samueal",
        "created_at" : "2011-03-09 10:31:02.765"
}
{
        "cust_id" : "sade",
        "created_at" : "2011-03-09 10:33:11.157"
}
{
        "cust_id" : "sade",
        "created_at" : "2011-03-10 10:33:35.595"
}
{
        "cust_id" : "samueal",
        "created_at" : "2011-03-10 10:39:06.388"
}
```

This is my mapReduce function

```
 m = function() { emit(this.cust_id, 1); }


    r = function (k, vals) { var sum = 0; for (var i in vals) { sum += vals[i]; } return sum; }


    q = function() {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()-32);
        var month = (currentDate.getMonth() < 10 ? "0"+ (currentDate.getMonth()+1) : (currentDate.getMonth()+1));
        var date = currentDate.getFullYear() + "-" + month ;
        var patt = new RegExp(date);
        var query = {"created_at":patt};
        return query;
    }


    res = db.logins.mapReduce(m, r, { query : q(), out :  "userLoginCountMonthly" });
```

With this i am geting the output as

```
{ "_id" : "sade", "value" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "samueal", "value" : 2 }
```

but i need genearte a Report  output in this format

For Example

```
Name            Date                Logins

sade            2011-03-09       1
sade            2011-03-10       2
samueal      2011-03-09       1
samueal      2011-03-10       1
```

Could anybody please help me how to achive , its

Edited Part

Currently I am getting the output as

```
  { "_id" : "dsstest 2011-03-09", "value" : 4 }
    { "_id" : "dsstest 2011-03-10", "value" : 14 }
```

Is it possible that i can get in this format

```
{ "_id" : "dsstest" , "date" : "2011-03-09", "value" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "dsstest" , "date" : "2011-03-10", "value" : 14 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping function is insufficient as it doesn't produce key that has the date in it.
I also don't quite understand why in the sample of what you want `sade` gets two logins. From what you are saying you want, you should need:

```
var m = function() {
   var aux = this.created_at.indexOf(' ');
   aux = this.created_at.substring(0,aux);

   // this 'if' block will filter out the entries you don't want
   // to be included in the result.
   if (aux < "2011-11-11") {
      return;
   }
   emit({cust:this.cust_id,day:aux},1);
}
var r = function(k, values) {
  var l = values.length;
  var r = 0;
  var i;
  for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
    r+=values[i];
  }
  return r;
}
```

And to run:

```
> db.logins.mapReduce(m, r, { query : q(), out :  "userLoginCountMonthly" });
```

And finally, to produce the report:

```
> db.userLoginCountMonthly.find().forEach(function(e){print(e._id.cust +' ' + e._id.day+' '+e.value);})
```

This would list the amount of logins for each user, for each day (within your search scope).

Comment: I am trying to modify my query so that it returns all Data from the collection if its less than Yesterday , but its giving a error , please see the edited part .

Comment: Storing dates as strings in the database is not the best way, as it really gets in the way of doing what you want. If all you want is just to not include today in the results, you are better off just ignoring the today's date in the final report, or modifying your map functions. I updated my answer with that.

Comment: Can't i use inside query as  var query = {created_at: {$lt: "2011-11-11"}}

Comment: Didn't you just say it was giving you an error? (Btw, it's always useful to let people know **what** the error actually is).

Comment: with this it worked , i was able to  get all the Data . You helped me a lot  , to be frank you saved my night

Comment: When i did a find on the collection , why its giving data in a different format ?? Its mixing up the User and the Date . please see my question the Edited Part

Comment: I was trying with different options but the emit function is giving error saying emit fast accepts only two parameters and i am getting confused .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29326/discussion-between-pawel-veselov-and-user974802)

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped me a lot and solved my requirement . Thanks Once again for helping .